# Ploty Dash: How to limit the Box Plot box hover decimal places to two in Python?

Tags: python, hover, plotly-dash

I have created a Dash application and added a box plot. The problem I am having is with the decimal places displayed on Hovering a box. I want to limit it to two. Already tried the suggestions mentioned on https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/ 2 but it’s not working. hover_data gives an error that it doesn’t exist. On another webpage, I have used JS plotly for box plots and used the hover formatting options to limit the decimal places mentioned on https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-text-and-formatting/#rounding-x-and-y-hover-values 2 and they worked perfectly. However, I am trying to sort it out in Dash but nothing is helping so far. Following is the code for one of the traces of Box plot.
Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated. Thanks :)

```
        y=dff['AA'],
        name="Sample1",
        boxmean=True,
        showlegend=True,
        boxpoints="suspectedoutliers",
        hovertemplate ='%{y:.2f}',
        pointpos=0,
        marker=dict(
            color='rgba(255, 65, 54, 0.5)'),
        line=dict(
            color='rgba(255, 65, 54, 0.5)')
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

`hover_data` is a member of plotly express.

`hovertemplate` is a member of the more robust, plotly graphing objects

So you cannot use them interchangeably.

https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/

Feel free to comment below and I can add on to this.  I'm not entirely sure if this is the problem you are referring to.